# Displaying Border on TextBlock when TextBlock placed inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have WPF application, In one of My WPF form has TextBlock. I placed TextBlock inside ScrollViewer for providing scrolling functionality. I want Border on TextBlock so, I have written following code in `XAML`.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="230,32,12,147">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
          <TextBlock Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>
      </Border>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

With scrollBar GUI displayed like below.

[image]

Bottom Border display on scroll down to the TextBlock. User Experience is not good for this design. So, I tried with below code but Border is not displaying.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="230,32,12,147">
          <TextBlock Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>
     </ScrollViewer>
 </Border>
```

How I can display Border When TextBlock placed inside ScrollViewer?

Comment: I solved with  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="230,32,12,147">
            <ScrollViewer >
                <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set border in ScrollViewer control!

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="230,32,12,147" BorderThickness="5">
      <TextBlock Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

In properties window, expand `Other` group and set `BorderThickness`

Next code works well:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="116"  Margin="115,112,0,0" Width="269">
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="5" Height="100" Width="200">
            <TextBlock Height="69" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" />
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

Code example for outside border:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="5" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,104,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
        <ScrollViewer Height="83" Name="sv" Width="184">
            <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock TextBlockTextBlockTextBlock TextBlock TextBlock TextBlock TextBlock TextBlockTextBlockTextBlock TextBlock TextBlock TextBloc TextBlock TextBlockTextBlockTextBlock TextBlock TextBlock TextBloc TextBlock TextBlockTextBlockTextBlock TextBlock TextBlock TextBloc" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set `BorderBrush` color?

Comment: Yes, Border is not displaying after setting BorderBrush="Black"

Comment: Ok, ScrollViewer's Border works in Silverlight, but not in WPF. Look at my answer, it was edited.

Comment: In your solution if I specified  Height & width property of Border then scrollbar is not displaying if I have 100 lines text in TextBlock. As my Question I want Both ScrollBar as well as Border outside Scrollviewer so, User Experience is good. You can see I achieved scrollbar and border in my question (see image). but problem with user experience. I want to display Border outside scrollviewer.

Comment: Yes, You are right It's working in Silverlight But I want that in WPF. my question on WPF.

Comment: I've tried your second code example. In this way, border will be displayed if you manually set border-width and border-height.

Comment: Thanks. Yes It's working if I specified Width and Height in Border style then It will Fix size. I don't want to fix size so, In my second solution I removed Margin property from Scrollviewer and put that in Border.